# converting stem shifters to brifters

Tags: maintenance, gears

I'm new. I'm 26, from the UK and until last year I'd never cycled more than 10 miles before. Then in September I cycled 2700 miles from Maine to Florida. It was great.

I've just bought a Dawes Galaxy, I believe made in about 1997. It's got a Shimano RSX rear derailleur, 7 speed, indexed shifters. Three cogs on the front with friction shifting. Shifters are on the down tube.

My plan is to buy some Shimano brifters. I was hoping to upgrade the down tube shifter into the integrated brake shifter. Could anyone give me advice on which Shimano sets would be compatible? I imagine any Shimano 3x7 would work. Is that correct?

Would these work?

1. http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Shimano-ST-3300-Sora-7-Speed-STI-Lever-/291470495079?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item43dcfecd67
2. http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/New-Shimano-Sora-ST-3300-7-7-Speed-Right-Hand-Side-STI-Shifter-Brake-Lever-/281698654774?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item41968c5a36

Other equipment I believe I'll need is: cable housing, wire, crimp tool, end caps, bar tape, cable tensioners ... What do I put in place of the current shifters, some sort of cable stop?

Anything else I would need? Anything else I need to consider?

Comment: By "main stem", I assume you mean the down tube. You might find a diagram like [this](http://www.jimlangley.net/wrench/bicycleparts.html) helpful since the names aren't always obvious. For the cable stops, you're looking for something like [these](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/down-tube-stops-fittings-dept668/) to bolt into the existing shifter braze-on.

Comment: Thanks and yes i meant the down tube, woops.
and thanks for the second link too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy any 7 speed Shimano brifter (or compatible ones made by Microshift). The ones you link to are fine. The front derailleur needs to be Shimano road.

You'll need:
- Cable stops on the downtube
- New cables and cable housing (brake and shift)
- Probably new bar tape

The tools will be cable and housing cutters, an awl, a file and some screwdrivers/hex keys.

Not sure what you mean by cable tensioners.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think i meant cable stops when i said tensioners. Still getting used to the terminology.

Can i clarify what you mean by shimano "road" for the front deraileur?
thanks again for the help!

Comment: Shimano makes mountain bike parts (altus, acera, alivio, deore, etc.) and road parts (claris, sora, tiagra, 105, etc.). In the pre-10 speed days, you could put whatever you wanted in the rear so long as it was Shimano. But the front had to be matched with the type of shifters (so road shifters, e.g. brifters, need a road front derailleur). RSX would be in the road group.

Comment: I imagine it would be road on a dawes. I know its a Shimano rsx rear deraileur and a hyperdrive crankset. I didn't realise the front deraileur would have a name as well.
I guess what you're saying is that the brifter on the right side will work with the 7 speed rsx but unless the fron deraileur is a road one i wont be able to have a left 3 speed brifter.
Did i get that right? thanks again, much appreciated batman!

Comment: Yep. But front derailleurs are less than 20 USD (e.g. Shimano Claris FD-2403, which should work is 19.99) if you don't have a road FD. Friction shifters don't care what kind of derailleurs you throw at it, so it could be anything.

Comment: Thanks Batman. Potentially last question... what would i need the awl and file for, i understand the rest.

Comment: Sorry i completely forgot, I am a bit clueless about the types, grades, endings of gear wire and cable housing i would need. Theres a jagwire 1.2mm 2300mm gear cable on Amazon i was thinking of using. And then i imagine 4mm cable housing to take 1.2mm gear cable would be the one to aim for.
Thanks once again!

Comment: If you're not sure about all the individual parts, take a look at the complete kits on [wiggle](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/cycle/gear-cables/), [chainreaction](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/gear-cables?f=2259), [SJS](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/cables-gear-dept962_pg1/) or another good retailer. Or, of course, find a good local bike shop and take it in.

Comment: "awl & file": you'll need these to rework the cut-off cable housings. The file or alternatively a Dremel to square off the cuts and the awl to open up the Teflon liners in the cable housings.

Comment: The complete kits are a good idea. You need different housing for brakes and shifters and they have everything in them. Even if you have a dremel to cut the housing (you need bike cable housing cutters otherwise), in all likelihood you'll need the awl and maybe the file.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that road and mountain cables have different cable ends (a road brake cable is like a dot candy where a mountain brake cable is like a small puck). So, you need a kit marked road+mtb or road.

Comment: Ahhhhh thanks to the Batman, I was wondering what would break first, your kindness or your helpfulness. (neither did)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAPViUrsl9U